# How do i get to run an existing MVC asp.net project from a github repo in my windows 10 local machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I have [this](https://github.com/am-b/testv4) test asp.net mvc project I'd like to successfully run in my local machine. Of all the solutions i have encountered online visual studio code seemed to be my best part in getting this project running, but I'm recieving a couple of build errors, namely:

- > 1.error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNet' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly
  >   reference?)
  >
  > 2. error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Rotativa' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
  >
  > 3. error CS0115: 'AnnouncementsController.Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override

  > 4. error CS2001- when running it via IIS in my Chrome browser.

My end goal is to tweak its css/html files but asp.net as a back-end is my main hurdle here.

So which are the **main** steps I'm missing? Like in ruby on rails i remember having to migrate the models/controllers of already existing projects when testing them on my local machine.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Please share the complete error details.

Comment: Just did, check it once again. Thanks.

Comment: Is .net framework on which application target is installed on the machine?

Comment: I haven't got you quite clear Mr Singh, are you trying to ask if .net framework  is installed in my machine? I'm using visual studio community which i guess comes pre-installed with all required .net development tools.

Answer (score 1):

> Of all the solutions i have encountered online visual studio code seemed to be my best part in getting this project running

There are NuGet packages in this project that need restoring. If you run this project in Visual Studio then it will run a NuGet package restore on build to retrieve the packages you don't already have on your local machine. As far as I'm aware Visual Studio Code does not support this. If you want to run this project you'll need to install Visual Studio Community.

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Comment: Alright Jacob i just did and I'm still receiving the same errors, how do i navigate from here sir? Thanks for reaching back.

Comment: How are you opening the project? Are you opening it in VS Community?

Comment: Yes in VS community,basically i build it and launch it in my chrome browser via IIS.

Comment: Can you confirm you're getting exactly the same errors?
If so, try checking the following setting. Tools -> Options -> Nuget Package Manager. Ensure the two checkboxes under 'Package Restore' are checked